# PHP $_FILES - adding values into another array?

Tags: php, file, file-upload

Can you add $_FILE array values into another array? For instance please see below:

```
    // Add file details into one array
    $upload = array (
        'file_name'             => $_FILES["userfile"]["name"],
        'file_type'             => $_FILES["userfile"]["type"],
        'file_size'             => $_FILES["userfile"]["size"],
        'file_error'            => $_FILES["userfile"]["error"],
        'file_tmp_name'         => $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"],
        'image_active'          => $image_active,
        'image_type_id'         => $image_type_id,
        'banner_page'           => $banner_page,
        'slider_caption'        => $slider_caption
    );
```

Is this ok?

Comment: Did you try it? What is the result?

Comment: be sure $_FILES["userfile"] is set and your code is ok

Answer (score 2):

Sure, why not, $_FILES is an array just like any other. Just try how move_uploaded_file behaves first.

Comment: Hi, This fall onto my next problem. I'm on a shared server and my upload_tmp_dir is set to 'none'. I am using the move_upload_file function and it isnt working, thats why i thought it might be a problem with adding the $_FILE array values into another array

Comment: Hi, can you fix it with `ini_set ("upload_tmp_dir", "your_tmp_dir");`?

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt work? I am put it in my codeigniter controller method but this failed to work...? Should it go in the controller?

Comment: Basically, it should work from anywhere. Did you get an error?  Make sure you enter the correct path. Also it might be a good idea to check with your host - some of them allow no uploads at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's perfectly fine, just as with any other kind of array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can copy the values of the variables to other variables!

Answer (score 0):

you should treat `$_FILES` is just another array which has a global scope. Infact [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) defines `$_FILES` as ***An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method***